# Error: unexpected token ';' at the end of a javascript statement

Tags: javascript

Just a side note before you try to help: I am a complete newbie. Try to keep things simple ;)
I am trying to code a way to store var values between webpages in HTML. So far I have not been very successful. The problem I am having at the moment is the error 'unexpected token, ';'' (when I paste it into the console on 'Ctrl+Shft+J'

---

```js
var cookieString = document.cookie;
var savedStats = 0;
var stats = 0;
var fsStat = 0;
var psStat = 0;
var testStat = 0;

function getStats() {
  function splitCookieString() {
    return savedStats = cookieString.split(',');
  }
  return stats = [savedstats[0], savedStats[savedstats.length - 1];
    return fsStat += stats[0];
    return psStat += stats[1];
    return testStat = 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

---

and it points to the end of the line:

---

```js
return stats = [savedstats[0], savedStats[savedstats.length -1];
```

---

Please help me! Also while I'm here, the Function 'getStats()' has a wierd thing going on where it makes me put two '}' to end it.

Comment: Look up what the `return` statement does

Comment: Why are you writing `return` on every line?? Look up what a function is in javascript (or any programming language), and think again about when you want to write `return`.

Comment: @engineeriscool That's not the only problem. It's a lack of understanding of the `return` keyword and the assignment operator. Multiple time returns are legal syntax (just that only the first will execute).

Comment: As I said, quite new to this stuff....  Thanks +engineer is cool, I'll try that tomorrow. +Tom-Lord, can you please elaborate on your point.  +arboreal84, if you can see more issues please do tell me so I can attempt to fix it. Also while I'm here, just spotted an issue or two... like I forgot to end the splitCookieString() function, hence the weird issue with the '}'.

Comment: Thanks @arboreal84. So I assume now I can return all the variables values in one return statement?

Comment: @nick-a constructive criticism?

Comment: Despite the fact this code is flawed, the error is being produced by this line not having a closing `]`: `return stats = [savedstats[0], savedStats[savedstats.length - 1];`

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted shows some problems around the understanding of:

- The [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) keyword (structured programming)
- The [assignment operator (`=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) (imperative programming)

I strongly recommend to develop some understanding of these concepts.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. What method of learning do rate highest? Also thanks for the change in attitude, your recommendation is very appropriate as I haven't spent long enough trying to learn the 'ropes' ( if I said 'strings' would that be an uncalled for pun?(its the best I could do on the spot)).

Comment: My advice for you is: 1) don't solve problems by trial and error, 2) force yourself to understand how and why things work. If there is a concept you don't understand, clarify it as soon as possible.